# Programmatically Inflated RadioButton layout_width does not match the layout file

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button

I'm adding RadioButtons programmatically:

```
RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) inflater.inflate(R.layout.radio_button, null);
...
radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
```

In the RadioButton layout file, the width is match_parent:

```
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:button="@null"
         android:drawableLeft="@drawable/check_selector"
         android:drawablePadding="@dimen/large"
         android:paddingBottom="@dimen/large"
         android:paddingTop="@dimen/large"
         android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
```

however after adding it to the RadioGroup it's width is wrap_content: "width: -2"

```
Timber.e("width: %s", radioGroupReason.getChildAt(radioGroupReason.getChildCount() -1).getLayoutParams().width);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

before adding view use it:

```
radioButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Comment: In order for this to work I also had to set radio button width to wider than radio group width could be. ??